# The output of addition of two matrices in my c program displays unexpected values

Tags: c, matrix

After compiling the code for the addition of two matrices the I am being displayed unexpected values that start with 63.. and are seven digits long. I have also initialized the resulting matrix(which is the sum of the first two).

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a[10][10],b[10][10],c[10][10],i,j,m1,m2,n1,n2;
    printf("Enter the order of the matrix a: ");
    scanf("%d%d",&m1,&n1);
    printf("Enter the order of the matrix b: ");
    scanf("%d%d",&m2,&n2);
    if(m1==m2&&n1==n2)
    {
        //input of the elements to the matrix 'a'
        printf("Enter the elements of the matrix a: ");
        for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n1;j++)
                scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }        
    }
    //input of the elements to the matrix 'b'
    printf("Enter the elements of the matrix b: ");
    for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n1;j++)
            scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
    }
    //initialization of the matrix 'c'
    for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n1;j++)
            c[i][j]=0;
    }
    //adding the matrices 'a' and 'b'
    for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n1;j++)
        {
            c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
            printf("%d  ",&c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
        printf("The matrices cannot be added");
}
```

Comment: `main()` is a strongly deprecated signature. Use prototype-stlye function signatures, here: `int main(void)`

Answer (score 4):

First the `if-else` is not properly constructed. The `}` just before

```
//input of the elements to the matrix 'b'
```

marks the end of the if-clause which is certainly not what you want here.

Apart from that,

```
printf("%d  ",&c[i][j]);
```

should have been

```
printf("%d  ",c[i][j]); // You don't need & while printing.
```

---

As a side note,

```
for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n1;j++)
            c[i][j]=0;
    }
```

is avoidable, you may not initialize `c[i][j]` to zero.
If you must initialize each element of `c` to zero, you could've done

```
int c[4][4]={0}; // partial-initilization forces rest of the elements to be zero
```

The standard says in ISO/IEC **9899:201x->6.79->21**

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.

The last point could be understood using **6.79->10**

> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
>   unsigned) zero;
>  — if it is an aggregate, every member is 
>   initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any 
>   padding is initialized  to zero bits;

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
 {
    for(j=0;j<n1;j++)
    {
        c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
        printf("%d  ",c[i][j]); // printf("%d  ",&c[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
```